# How to sum object values with the same keys and return one object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to sum the object values based on selected keys which are available in every object of the array. My problem is how to handle the `percentage rate`. In the sample of code below, the `satisfaction_rate` should have `48`.

My output should be:

`{
  'students' : 87,
  'books': 32,
  'satisfaction_rate': 48
  }`

```js
const myData = [
  {
  'students' : 30,
  'books': 10,
  'satisfaction_rate': "60%",
  'returning_students': 14
  }, {
'students' : 25,
'books': 8,
'satisfaction_rate': "45%",
'returning_students': 14
  }, {
'students' : 32,
'books': 14,
'satisfaction_rate': "39%",
'returning_students': 19
  }
];


const keysToConsider = ['students', 'books', 'satisfaction_rate'];

function getSumOrAvgValuesOfKeys(data){
      const obj = {};
      let val = 0;
      keysToConsider.forEach(el => {
        data.forEach(element => {
          if (typeof(element[el] === 'string')) {
            val += parseInt(element[el], 10);
          } else {
            val += element[el];
          }
      });
        obj[el] = val;
        // Reset value
        val = 0;
    });
    return obj;
  }
  
console.log(getSumOrAvgValuesOfKeys(myData));
```

Comment: How is `satisfaction_rate` calculated for each item?

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil The API data is in that format. I don't know how it was calculated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `reduce` method and then on the last iteration calculate average for each element where value is type of string.

```js
const myData = [{"students":30,"books":10,"satisfaction_rate":"60%","returning_students":14},{"students":25,"books":8,"satisfaction_rate":"45%","returning_students":14},{"students":32,"books":14,"satisfaction_rate":"39%","returning_students":19}]

const keys = ['students', 'books', 'satisfaction_rate'];

const result = myData.reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
  keys.forEach(k => r[k] = (r[k] || 0) + parseInt(e[k]));
  if(!a[i + 1]) Object.keys(e)
    .filter(k => typeof e[k] == 'string')
    .forEach(k => r[k] /= myData.length)
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have another array with keys to be averaged, and after the preparation of the summed result, you can calculate the average for those keys only.

```js
const myData = [{
  'students': 30,
  'books': 10,
  'satisfaction_rate': "60%",
  'returning_students': 14
}, {
  'students': 25,
  'books': 8,
  'satisfaction_rate': "45%",
  'returning_students': 14
}, {
  'students': 32,
  'books': 14,
  'satisfaction_rate': "39%",
  'returning_students': 19
}];


const keysToConsider = ['students', 'books', 'satisfaction_rate'];
let keysWithPercent = ['satisfaction_rate'];

const summed = myData.reduce((result, item) => {
  keysToConsider.forEach(k => {
    if (!result[k]) {
      result[k] = 0;
    }
    
    let v = parseInt(item[k], 10);
    result[k] += v;
  });
  
  return result;
}, {});

keysWithPercent.forEach(k => {
  summed[k] = summed[k] / myData.length;
})

console.log(summed);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the objects by taking the previous values or a default value. For the percent value take a third for summing.

```js
var data = [{ students: 30, books: 10, satisfaction_rate: "60%", returning_students: 14 }, { students: 25, books: 8, satisfaction_rate: "45%", returning_students: 14 }, { students: 32, books: 14, satisfaction_rate: "39%", returning_students: 19 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { students, books, satisfaction_rate }, _, a) => ({
        students: (students || 0) + students,
        books: (r.books || 0) + books,
        satisfaction_rate: (r.satisfaction_rate || 0) + satisfaction_rate.slice(0, -1) / a.length
    }), {});
      
console.log(result);
```

With a dynamic key list

```js
var data = [{ students: 30, books: 10, satisfaction_rate: "60%", returning_students: 14 }, { students: 25, books: 8, satisfaction_rate: "45%", returning_students: 14 }, { students: 32, books: 14, satisfaction_rate: "39%", returning_students: 19 }],
    keys = ['students', 'books', 'satisfaction_rate'],
    result = data.reduce((r, o, _, a) => 
        Object.assign(
            ...keys.map(k =>
                ({ [k]: (r[k] || 0) + (o[k].toString().endsWith('%')
                    ? o[k].slice(0, -1) / a.length
                    : o[k])
                }))
        ),
        {}
    );
      
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, what you are trying to do can be done using `reduce` like this:

```js
var myData = [{ students: 30, books: 10, satisfaction_rate: "60%", returning_students: 14 }, { students: 25, books: 8, satisfaction_rate: "45%", returning_students: 14 }, { students: 32, books: 14, satisfaction_rate: "39%", returning_students: 19 }]

var result = myData.reduce((accum, { students, books, satisfaction_rate }, idx, arr) => {
    accum["students"] ? (accum["students"] += students) : (accum["students"] = students);
    accum["books"] ? (accum["books"] += books) : (accum["books"] = books);
    accum["satisfaction_rate"] ? (accum["satisfaction_rate"] += parseInt(satisfaction_rate)) : (accum["satisfaction_rate"] = parseInt(satisfaction_rate));
    if (idx === arr.length - 1) {
      accum["satisfaction_rate"] = accum["satisfaction_rate"] / arr.length
    }
return accum;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution would be to specify **how you want to reduce** each key in your `keysToConsider` object. You could reduce them using SUM, AVG, MIN, MAX, and even more complex ones like standard deviation.

In that case, I would change your `keysToConsider` to be an object rather than an array:

```js
const myData = [{
    'students': 30,
    'books': 10,
    'satisfaction_rate': "60%",
    'returning_students': 14
}, {
    'students': 25,
    'books': 8,
    'satisfaction_rate': "45%",
    'returning_students': 14
}, {
    'students': 32,
    'books': 14,
    'satisfaction_rate': "39%",
    'returning_students': 19
}];

keysToConsider = {
    'students': sum,
    'books': sum,
    'satisfaction_rate': avg
}

function reduceValuesOfKeys(data) {
    const obj = {};
    let val = 0;
    for (var p in keysToConsider) {
        var reduce = keysToConsider[p];
        obj[p] = reduce(data, p);
    }
    return obj;
}

function sum(data, property) {
    var val = 0;
    data.forEach(element => {
        if (typeof(element[property] === 'string')) {
            val += parseInt(element[property], 10);
        } else {
            val += element[property];
        }
    });
    return val;
}

function avg(data, property) {
    var val = 0;
    data.forEach(element => {
        if (typeof(element[property] === 'string')) {
            val += parseInt(element[property], 10);
        } else {
            val += element[property];
        }
    });
    return val / data.length;
}

console.log(reduceValuesOfKeys(myData));
```

If you needed to add other reduce functions in the future, it'd be easier.